# "Different influences"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

> Then trade would have different **influence** on wages and employment.

This is a line I am writing. I know that "influence" is both a count and noncount noun and that it is used mostly uncountably to refer to effects. But since I am talking about different kinds of influence, I am wondering if I should say:

> Then trade would have different **influences** on wages and employment.

Answer (score 2):

While the plural "influences" makes sense, it's an awkward sentence.  Since your purpose is to make a distinction between the two influences, I prefer something like Tashus' phrasing:

> The trade would have **a different influence** on wages **than** on employment.

or

> The influence of the trade on wages **would be different from** its influence on employment.

These make clear both the meaning and intention of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In this context you should use "**influences**". Trade has one influence on wages and another on employment. The use of the adjective "different" would not make sense with a singular "influence", as how can you draw a comparison if there are not two things to compare?